# how to swipe the multiple images in single view in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I made multiple image swipping in single view.In that app,there is only one view that has an image on it. I want to be able to swipe left to right and right to left and have the first image go out of the view and the second image to come in.I am trying the code.But it is not worked for me.Please any body guide me.I am new to the image swipping.Thanks in advance.

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 190)];   
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
scrollView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrollWidth = 120;    
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth,80);    
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSError *err;
    NSString *strResponse=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"response is %@",strResponse);

    dict1=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&err];

    NSLog(@"vals are %@",dict1);

    NSString *strImg;
    url=@"myimageurl";
    str=[dict1 valueForKey:@"image_names"];

    arrImages=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

   for(int index=0; index < [arrImages count]; index++)   
   {       
        NSLog(@"image: %@",[arrImages objectAtIndex:index]);
        if (str!=nil) 
        {  
            strImg=[url stringByAppendingString:[arrImages objectAtIndex:index]];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{

                NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strImg]];

               if(data == nil) return;

               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                   UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData: data];
                   imgView.image=img;
               });
            });
        }
    }
}




- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
     UITouch * touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    for(int index=0;index<[arrImages count];index++)
    {
        UIImageView *imgView = [arrImages objectAtIndex:index];

        NSLog(@"x=%f,y=%f,width =%f,height=%f",imgView.frame.origin.x,imgView.frame.origin.y,imgView.frame.size.width,imgView.frame.size.height);

        NSLog(@"x= %f,y=%f",[touch locationInView:self.view].x,[touch locationInView:self.view].y) ;

        if(CGRectContainsPoint([imgView frame], [touch locationInView:scrollview]))
        {
            [self ShowDetailView:imgView];
            break;
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Any body help me please

Comment: Any body help me please.i am struck this issue..still i have not find a solution.........

Answer (score 0):

First of all set the pagingEnabled property `scrollview.pagingEnabled = YES;`.
Then set the correct `contentSize` for the `scrollView`.
And last but not least you must set the `width` of `contentSize` to be a multiple of `scrollView.frame.size.width`.

I.E. If you have 3 images and your `scrollView` has a `width` of 320 pixel you `contentSize` must be 320x3 = 960 pixel

Comment: thanks for your response.I am adding scrollview.pagingEnabled = YES; line of code in -(void)viewDidLoad method.But still it is not working...

Comment: If you're using InterfaceBuilder with XIB put the code inside `viewDidLoad` otherwise in `loadView`.
Edit you answer and show me the updated code you have written.

Comment: thanks for your response.but if i put the code in loadview getting threads like exceptions.so please guide me.Thanks in advance....

Comment: you forgot to call `[super loadView]`

Comment: thanks for your response.i tried to ur suggested method.Right now errors are not displayed.But image does not swipping..

Comment: You are completely wrong the UIImageView add... You must to add the UIImageView on the scrollView and set a frame for every UIImageView

Answer (score 0):

You may want to **adjust `scrollView.contentSize.width`** by `amountOfImages * scrollWidth`.

---

Beside this, you really should create a new object for every image.

It could handle image downloading, validating, and touch handling (even with a single transparent button upont the image). You could completly wipe out that weird `touchesBegan` code from your controller, and you could forget about coordinates entirely.

Also you could stop progressing downloads that have way scrolled out this way, so performance can grow.

Answer (score 0):

```
    .h file #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate,UIScrollViewAccessibilityDelegate>

    {
        UIScrollView  *scrView;
        NSMutableArray *arrimage;
        UIImageView *imgview;
    }
    @end
.M file
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 465);

    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [scrollView setAlwaysBounceVertical:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    arrimage = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1.jpeg",@"2.jpeg",@"3.jpeg",@"4.jpeg",@"5.jpeg",@"6.jpeg",@"7.jpeg",@"8.jpeg",@"9.jpeg",@"10.jpeg", nil];

    for (int i = 0; i < [arrimage count]; i++)
    {
        CGFloat xOrigin = i * scrollView.frame.size.width;

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)];
        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrimage objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

        [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    }

    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * [arrimage count], scrollView.frame.size.height)];
}
```